# Уникальный идентификатор объекта

Tags: java

Пишу сервер на NIO2. Для каждого подключившегося клиента создается объект, который обрабатывает его события. Хочется все логировать и при этом в лог писать некий уникальный идентификатор, скажем, аналог адреса объекта. В Java есть что-то встроенное или писать свой инкрементный счетчик?

Comment: UUID можно юзать

Comment: @SeniorPomidor Длинно. Потом в логах фиг разберешься

Comment: то есть вы точно знаете, что подключений будет меньше integer.MAX? в лог пишите `[UUID][client ip] - log info`. тогда это станет более понятнее.

Comment: Что насчет `RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(n)`.

Comment: @GVArt И молиться, чтобы не сгенерировались одинаковые значения

Answer (score 3, accepted):

можно не использовать синхронизацию, ведь есть  [AtomicInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html)

```
public class Client {

    private static AtomicInteger at = new AtomicInteger(0);

    public int getNext(){
        return at.incrementAndGet();
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Забыл про него

Answer (score 0):

Сделал так

```
public class Client {
    private static int counter = 0;

    private synchronized static int nextCounter() {
        return counter++;
    }

    public final int index = nextCounter();
    .............
}
```

Comment: final потом нельзя переинициализировать вроде.

Comment: @SeniorPomidor Ну да. Именно как мне и нужно. Для каждого клиента создается свой объект с уникальным индексом.

Answer (score 0):

Есть несколько вариантов, что использовать в качестве идентификатора:

- значение функции `hashCode()`. Использовать только с имутабельными объектами либо с теми, где значение функции не зависит от изменяемого состояния
- значение `new Random().nextLong()`
- либо `UUID.randomUUID().toString()`

Comment: `Random().nextLong()` не гарантирует, что два объекта не получат один идентификатор

Comment: конечно как и счетчик с типом `int`. Потому что рано или поздно произойдет переполнение и он пойдет по второму кругу.

Comment: Нет. Он выдает **случайные** значения. Например, он может выдать такую последовательность `5, 15, 12, 12, 6`. Да, такое событие маловероятно, но оно возможно

Comment: да, но вероятность колизии `1/(Integer.MAX_VALUE-INTEGER.MIN_VALUE)`. и это тоже очень маловероятно

Comment: Нет. Это вероятность выпадения одного, конкретно заданного, числа. Вероятность коллизии существенно выше. Кроме того вероятность и частота выпадения это разные вещи. Частота стремится к вероятности при приближении числа опытов к бесконечности

Comment: Хм. действительно

Comment: https://ideone.com/hiOUUX На 1000 запусках Min: 1734, Max: 248621, Avg: 83092

Comment: @AntonShchyrov интересные результаты,спасибо